# Dynamically update the web config for webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

I have few a web services which I have configured in the web application. In that I have set all the webservices as dynamic. So I can see all the webservices in the `web.config` file.

For example:

```
<applicationSettings>
    <WebInterface.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="WebInterface_CustomerCard_CustomerCard_Service"
       serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://localhost:7047/DynamicsNAV/WS/Supratechnic%20(M)%20Sdn%20Bhd/Page/CustomerCard</value>
      </setting>
</WebInterface.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
```

In the login page I need to change these webservices dynamically at runtime and save it in `web.config` at the time of login. How can I change it in the code behind?

Comment: *Very* bad idea. Web.config is *not* the place to store runtime configuration data. Modifying it will force the application pool to recycle. If you want to modify settings at runtime store them somewhere else, eg. in a database table

Comment: Then how ? based on the company he login in i need to change the webserviecs dynamically

Comment: I suggest you post a question with your actual problem, not your attempted solution - do you have a multitenant application or do you simply want to change the URL for production deployment?  Anyway, you don't "change the webservices dynamically". You can call any web service simply by changing the URL you pass to your client's constructor. The setting in web.config is simply the default value.

Answer (score 1):

Web.config is not the right place for a change like this because it is shared among all users. Your application can be used by several users at the same time so this change would affect many of them instead of just one. In a secure environment, your application is not able to write to web.config anyway and - as also @PanagiotisKanavos points out - writing to it would recycle the app pool right away.

A better way to achieve this is to provide the URL when you instantiate the web service client as a constructor argument. You'd add a second URL to your web.config, maybe in the AppSettings section. In the login page, you decide which URL is the right one for the user and save it in a place that is specific for the user e.g. in Session state. Whenever you create an instance of the client, you retrieve the URL and provide it to the constructor.

Comment: Modifying `web.config` will recycle the application pool so it's definitely *not* the place to store runtime configuration settings.